# What was supposed to convince the people who lived during middle ages that islam is the truth

Tags: islamic-philosophy

This question has been keeping me up at night.When the prophet (PBUH) preached islam in arab,he performed many miracles to convince them that this is the truth.The same is true for all other prophets.So the arabs during that time who didn't accept islam will have to answer to Allah,because they saw signs yet they were blinded.

But then when islam spread to other parts of the world during the middle ages,what is it that was supposed to convince them that this is the truth.I mean,the scientific and numerical miracles weren't discovered at that time.There were so many religions iin excistenceSo how were they supposed to know which is the truth and which isn't?What is it that Allah (SWT)is going to accuse them of?

Comment: Allah will accuse them of Shirk (polytheism), worshiping someone other than Allah. The fact that polytheism cannot be true is self-evident, if only people pondered.

Comment: Muhammad didn't perform "many miracles" during his ministry. It is repeatedly said that he is "only a warner" and that he doesn't do miracles (see Qur'an 10:20; 11:12; 13:7, 27; 29:50; 67:25-26). The miracle assigned to his ministry is the Qur'an, and that was what was supposed to convince people after his death.

Answer (score -1):

There are many, many signs to make evident that Islam is the truth regardless of time period. The miracles were one sign; the scientific foreknowledge in the Qur'an is another sign. It doesn't stop there though.

Another sign: Islam is unique in that the Qur'an A) gives logical evidence as to why it is the truth and B) gives logical evidence as to why other religions are false. (See my post: "[Disbelief Shattered](https://veiledink.wordpress.com/2019/05/12/allahs-%EF%B7%BB-guidance-disbelief-shattered/)"). All that was needed was sincerity in faith and desire to seek truth. Allah (ﷻ) guides the sincere.

Moreover, even the Bible leads people to Islam, as many ex-Christians report, from the remnants of truth left in it. e.g., Jesus (pbuh) calls himself a Prophet but never God. And, even Prophet Muhammad's (ﷺ) name (מחמד) is found in Hebrew in the Bible!

In conclusion, there are many signs and ways people are lead to Islam.

P.S Those people in the Middle Ages whom the message of Islam may have not reached (or did not reach properly) will be tested in the Hereafter inshaAllah, per scholars.